# iPhone SDK: TextView, Keyboard in Landscape mode

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, keyboard, uitextview, landscape

How do I make sure that the textview is shown and the keyboard is not obscuring the textview, while in landscape.

Using UICatalog I created a TextViewController which works. In it there are two methods for calling the keyboard and making sure that textView is positioned above the keyboard. his just works great in Portrait mode.

I got the Landscape mode working, but on the textView is still being put to the top of the iPhone to compensate for the keyboard in portrait mode.

I changed the methods for showing the keyboards.

Below is the code for this methods: (I will just let see the code for show, since the hide code will be the reverse..

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification 
{
 UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
 if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
   // the keyboard is showing so resize the table's height
  CGRect keyboardRect = [[[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
  NSTimeInterval animationDuration = [[[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
  CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
  frame.size.height -= keyboardRect.size.height;
  [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:nil];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
  self.view.frame = frame;
  [UIView commitAnimations];
 } else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
  NSLog(@"Left"); // Verijderen later
  CGRect keyboardRect = [[[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
  NSTimeInterval animationDuration = [[[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
  CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
  frame.size.width -= keyboardRect.size.height;
  [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:nil];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
  self.view.frame = frame;
  [UIView commitAnimations];
 } else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
  NSLog(@"Right"); // verwijderen later.
  CGRect keyboardRect = [[[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
  NSTimeInterval animationDuration = [[[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
  CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
  frame.size.width -= keyboardRect.size.width;
  [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:nil];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
  self.view.frame = frame;
  [UIView commitAnimations];
 }

}
```

I know that I have to change the line `frame.size.height -= keyboardRect.size.height` but I do not seem to get it working.

I tried `frame.size.width -= keyboardRect.size.height` that did not work. Losing the keyboardRect and frame all together work, however off course the keyboard obscures the textview........

Answer (score 1):

I found the above code wouldn't work when in Landscape Mode on iPad

Note: I am moving all Fields, as in my case that's what i needed :-)

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
// Only do for Landscape Mode

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([self interfaceOrientation])){
        NSDictionary *info = [aNotification userInfo];
        NSValue *aValue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey];
        CGSize keyboardSize = [aValue CGRectValue].size;

        NSTimeInterval animationDuration = 0.300000011920929;
        CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
        frame.origin.x -= keyboardSize.height-44;
        frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height-44;
        frame.size.height += keyboardSize.height-44;
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
        self.view.frame = frame;
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        viewMoved = YES;
    }
    keyboardInUse = YES;
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([self interfaceOrientation])){
        if (viewMoved) {

            NSDictionary *info = [aNotification userInfo];
            NSValue *aValue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey];
            CGSize keyboardSize = [aValue CGRectValue].size;

            NSTimeInterval animationDuration = 0.300000011920929;
            CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
            frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height-44;
            frame.origin.x += keyboardSize.height-44;
            frame.size.height -= keyboardSize.height-44;
            [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
            self.view.frame = frame;
            [UIView commitAnimations];

            viewMoved = NO;
        }
    }
    keyboardInUse = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think you need different code for the different orientations, you're doing something else wrong. Once the orientation has changed and your superview has responded, the value that needs changing should *always* be the frame's height.

Comment: If this is true why does this code: CGRect keyboardRect = [[[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
  NSTimeInterval animationDuration = [[[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
  CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
  frame.size.height -= keyboardRect.size.height;
  [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:nil];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
  self.view.frame = frame;
  [UIView commitAnimations];
result in a view that moves to the right while in Landscape mode?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that I use for this purpose.  It works on both iPad and iPhone is landscape and portrait modes (inspired by a code from Apple documentation):

```
// Call this method somewhere in your view controller setup code.
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

float offset;
if UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)
    offset = kbSize.height;
else
    offset = kbSize.width;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect frameTxtField = myTextField.frame;
                     frameTxtField.origin.y -= offset;
                     myTextField.frame = frameTxtField;
                 }
 ];  

}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

float offset;
if UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)
    offset = kbSize.height;
else
    offset = kbSize.width;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect frameTxtField = myTextField.frame;
                     frameTxtField.origin.y += offset;
                     myTextField.frame = frameTxtField;
                 }
 ];  
}
```

Don't forget to call the registerForKeyboardNotifications method (e.g., in viewDidLoad).